# Create mongodb database using Laravel command

Tags: laravel, mongodb

How to create mongdb database using laravel command? I manage to create mysql database using laravel command but it doesn't work for the coding.

```
public function handle()
{
    ...
    config(["database.connections.".$cur['db_conn'].".database" => null]);
    $query = "CREATE DATABASE $schemaName;";
    DB::statement($query);
```

Comment: https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

Comment: github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb use for query collection.

My challenges is to create mongo database.

Comment: Databases & collections in MongoDB are implicitly created when you first store data. Is it possible (but optional) to explicitly create collections with options like collation or schema validation, but there is currently no command to create a database.